# Can a mini Page Layout(displays when you hover on a lookup field) be disabled in Classic?

Tags: mini-page-layout

Is there a way to easily disable mini Page Layouts per Profile?
I'm avoiding the pop up that would show Insufficient Privileges if the user has no view access and hovers on the Contact field(e.g.).

My work around to disable it is creating a text field replacing the lookup field and creating a workflow field update to populate the new text field. However, in most cases, one Profile needs the hover functionality and another Profile don't need it so I need a new Page layout that displays the text field for the other Profile that don't need the hover. Going through that whole process takes more time if I have to do it on more than one object.

Anybody who has an idea about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover details are unfortunately governed by a single setting, found in Setup > Customize > User Interface, named "Enable Hover Details." You can either disable it for every lookup field everywhere for all users, or not at all. You'll have to figure out if its worth your time to try and implement this in a consistent manner, but there's no easy way to do this by simply checking a box.